# Show / Hide divs individually with same class name

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying a really easy thing, hiding / showing an info div my mouse-hovering another element. My code structure is similar to:

```
<div class="divRow">
    <div class="divColumn">
        <div class="divInfo">Info</div><a href=""><img src="" /></a></div>
        <div class="divInfo">Info</div><a href=""><img src="" /></a></div>
        <div class="divInfo">Info</div><a href=""><img src="" /></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Image is shown, and there should be a blank space in which I want divInfo to appear.

I am using the following jQuery code to show / hide:

```
$(function() {
      $('.divInfo').hide();
      $('.divColumn').hover( function() { $('.divInfo').toggle(); } );
});
```

Of course, this works, but shows / hides all 3 divs in the row at a time. I want to be able to show hide each one separately...

Is this possible using classes? Or do I have to use a different unique ID for each??

Functionality I want is shown here, but I don't know how to do that. :)

http://www.therice-co.com

Regards and thanks

Comment: You can reference them by array index based on class name.

Comment: @cfqueryparam Sorry but I don't know how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by individually? If it is "one after the other" you might be able to use `.each()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you want the divs to always be there but somehow "not visible" when you are not hovering them. This is as simple as:

```
.divInfo:not(:hover){
    opacity: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_abl/uxkuLLka/)

Comment: Thank you, that does exactly what I need in the simplest way! I have checked the other answers and also work, but much more complex!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.divColumn').children('a').hover(function () { // bind it to exact image
    $(this).prev('.divInfo').toggle(); // show previous div
});
```

will work

**[jQuery DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/k6k573hn/)**

but you definetely have too much closing `</div>`s

also you can do it with pure CSS if you wrap each info and image in separate div and use `:hover` on it

**[PURE CSS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/97pgjyow/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

This is what are you trying to achieve

[image]

see http://jsfiddle.net/j0aoy47L/

Javascript

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $('.divInfo').hover( function() {
         $(this).find('.info').toggle(); 
   } );
});
</script>
```

CSS

```
    <style>
  .info{
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .divInfo{
    background: #fcfcfc;
    border:1px solid #e5e5e5;
    width:360px;
    height:200px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding:10px;
  }
  .divInfo img{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 9px;
    left: 19px;
  }
</style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="divRow">
<div class="divColumn">
    <div class="divInfo">
       <div class="info"><h4>Image Caption</h4> <p>Some image information</p></div> 
       <img src="http://placehold.it/350x100/addd" />
    </div>
    <div class="divInfo">
       <div class="info"><h4>Image Caption</h4> <p>Some image information</p></div> 
       <img src="http://placehold.it/350x100/addd" />
    </div>
    <div class="divInfo">
       <div class="info"><h4>Image Caption</h4> <p>Some image information</p></div> 
       <img src="http://placehold.it/350x100/addd" />
    </div>
</div>
```